# Как настроить заголовок ответа в Yii?

Tags: header, php, yii, кэширование

Простой вопрос: как Yii настроить так, чтоб в случае если страница не менялась со времени последнего обращения, отдавался бы заголовок Not Modified ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не сталкивался с подобной задачей, и [зависимость](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/caching.data#sec-2) кэша использовал только в ознакомительных целях. Но у зависимостей есть [метод](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCacheDependency#getHasChanged-detail), который Вы можете использовать.
Т.е. например:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM tbl_post'); //тут Вы определяете зависимость, когда страница считается измененной
if(!$dependency->getHasChanged()) //данные поменялись, раз можем получить значения
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
```